# Get password when user registers and save it sha1 into database

Tags: theme-development, functions, filters, hooks, password

im working on a website where the users can connect with iphone to some functions of it by using a sha1 encrypted password. In other words the plain password of wordpress encrypted in sha1.

In the past i did the silly thing of editing the core files of wordpress to get the password when the user register and save that password in sha1 on the wp_users table.

Of course my client updated wordpress and all the functions were lost. Yeah im stupid, im not sure what i was thinking that day.

There is any way to hook to the register function to get the password , encrypt it in sha1 format and storeit in the database from the functions.php file of my theme?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Pluggable Functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions) in `/wp-includes/pluggable.php`. You can safely replace the password generating/checking functions with your own.

Comment: I dont want to replace wordpress register method, just add a function to it. The password when user register will be saves as normally. I want to save a sha1 encrypted pass into another table cell

Comment: @chifliiiii - i believe the only way to get the plaintext password is to replace `wp_hash_password` function with essentially the same function, but add your own sha1 hash and insert into a table. look in `/wp-includes/user.php` at `wp_insert_user` and `wp_update_user` where `wp_hash_password` is called. there don't appear to be any hooks that give you access to plaintext, just the hash.

Comment: At end i modified i added my own hook in user.php and plugable.php

Comment: @chifliiiii - just to clarify, anything you want to modify in `pluggable.php` should go in your own plugin, not directly in `pluggable.php`, as that will get overwritten when you update.

Answer (score 1):

You can hook into [`wp_check_password()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_password), which does this at end:

```
return apply_filters('check_password', $check, $password, $hash, $user_id);
```

If `$check` is `true` then `$password` is current valid pass for `$user_id`.

Note that this will only work next time specific user logins. You can't just retrieve plan text passwords for all accounts.

Comment: CAn you explain me a bit better how to do that?Im really new to hooks and still dont get it right