# Pass variable to hook. Its possible?

Tags: theme-development, functions, filters, hooks

I have this hook created to retrieve user password when he register or update his pass. I dont want my client to touch wordpress core so i was planning to use a hook in wp-includes/user.php
All this come from [this other post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28455/get-password-when-user-registers-and-save-it-sha1-into-database) as i cant find any other better solution

MY problem is that the hook is being called but variables are empty.

```
function encrypt_password_function($pass, $id){
    global $wpdb;
    $encrypted=sha1($pass);
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_users SET iphone_pass = %s WHERE ID = %d",array($encrypted, '10')));
}


function encrypt_password() {
    do_action('encrypt_password');
}
add_action('encrypt_password', 'encrypt_password_function', 1);
```

Comment: How and where are you calling these functions? `encrypt_password()` without any arguments and with hook inside doesn't make sense.

Comment: Im calling in wp-includes/user.php inside wp_insert_user function like these: encrypt_password($plain_password, $user_id); I get the plain password var before password get hashed.

Comment: ok now i realized i was doing wrong the add_action. But now the pass is hashed and nto plain like it says on the function description :(

Comment: Are you modifying core file to run this? Just don't. I won't even go there. :)

Comment: I cant find any other way to get plain password when user register or update his password :(

Comment: Ok i can pass variables to hook but  i was doing it wrong. Code should be:

    function encrypt_password_function($pass, $id){
        global $wpdb;
        $encrypted=sha1($pass);
        $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_users SET iphone_pass = %s WHERE ID = %d",array($encrypted, '10')));
    }
    
    
    function encrypt_password($var1, $var2) {
        do_action('encrypt_password',$var1,$var2);
    }
    add_action('encrypt_password', 'encrypt_password_function', 1,2);

Comment: You have got couple very valid suggestions in your other question. Please try to go through those, before dragging this one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i can pass variables to hook but  i was doing it wrong. Code should be:

```
function encrypt_password_function($pass, $id){
    global $wpdb;
    $encrypted=sha1($pass);
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_users SET iphone_pass = %s WHERE ID = %d",array($encrypted, '10')));
}


function encrypt_password($var1, $var2) {
    do_action('encrypt_password',$var1, $var2);
}
add_action('encrypt_password', 'encrypt_password_function', 1,2);
```